# Amazon EC2 Permission denied (publickey) for every new key pair I create

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

My first key pair (eyelid_s.pem) is working fine. I'm using this key pair as access to an instance for personal use.

Now I'd like to create a new instance for a team to work on, so I created a new key pair (SE_Server.pem) as the default key pair for the new instance. But it just doesn't work. Even the old pem doesn't work for the new instance. I've tried new key pairs on my first instance, but they don't work either.

I've already done this:

```
chmod 400 SE_Server.pem
```

So this shouldn't be the file permission problem.

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-23-20-118-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com  [2001:778::ffff:64:0:1714:7660] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Lynn/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lynn/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lynn/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lynn/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 4d:28:fd:e1:aa:ba:89:9a:6e:e7:b3:d7:fa:15:bd:af
debug1: Host 'ec2-23-20-118-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Lynn/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Lynn/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Lynn/eyelid_s.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: SE_Server_key.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Lynn/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'd really be grateful if anyone can help me! This is really really annoying because I have no access to my new instance.

Comment: You can have single Amazon key per Instance. Check if you are using the same key connecting your Instance as you started it. You can check  it with AWS Console or API Tools. BTW, once you started new instance, I suggest you to deploy your own public key to it so that you don't need to add `-i path/to/your.pem` each time you ssh it.

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple keys (not in AWS console, but you can use them to ssh into your machine), just make sure you add them into the "authorized_keys" or "authorized_keys2" depending on your ssh version.

http://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/pubkey2ssh.c - a way to import the .pem but im sure there are other methods out there to.